# HUDSON - SVN TAG plugin works on one job but not another

Tags: java, svn, hudson

I setup the SVN TAG plugin for Hudson and I get the following error after a successful build:

```
SvnTag plugin does not support tagging for SCM hudson.scm.NullSCM@6f0c3e55.
```

JOB #1 works fine, but is dependent on a source code change to trigger the build. We have 'Source Code Management' set to 'Subversion' in this job.

JOB #2 is where I have a problem. All this job does is move the files from our repository trunk folder into the production source code folder. We have 'NONE' selected on this job for the 'Source Code Management', so this job is NOT dependent on a commit or change to build.

Does anyone know why I would be getting this error on a successful build in hudson?

Comment: i never used the svn tag plugin. But how can the job copy files from a repository when source code management is deactivated for it?

Comment: I figured on a successful build that it would still do the tagging using the plugin. All the build in JOB #2 does is moves the files from our trunk into the live code area.

Comment: Looks like the tagging plugin is forcing to activate itself although you didn't check it in JOB#2, and since you set SCM to NONE (I guess NullSCM is the SCM implementation that represents the NONE option) it doesn't know how to tag, thus the error. Has the job configuration any óther (maybe hidden) options concerning the SVN TAG plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is happening.  From the plugin documentation: *This plugin obtains the authentication information directly from Hudson core's Subversion SCM class so the principal and credential specified here is used for subversion authentication*. That core class is not specified for the job object if you do not use 'Source Code Management' step.

The obvious work-around: define Source Code Management step, but do not use it as a trigger. The drawback: the job will waste time on trying to update the working copy.

Another workaround (I'm not sure that it will work, but worth a shot): use [BlameSubversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BlameSubversion). It will do no harm and will define that 'hudson.scm' object. That object, however, may not contain methods/data that the tagging plugin requires.